# missing "=" after "conn_db_link" in connection info string

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I've been trying to figure out the issue here.   This is running in a bash script.  And I am getting the error below.  However, if I run the INSERT statement manually from within psql, it works fine.

```
psql -U zrec -d zrec -t -c "INSERT INTO approved_recommendations
                              SELECT * FROM dblink('conn_db_link','SELECT * FROM approved_recommendations') AS x(
                                ticker                   varchar,
                                status                   varchar,
                                approved_recommendation  integer,
                                yesterday_recommendation integer,
                                prior_recommendation     integer,
                                date_approved            date,
                                approved_by              integer,
                                date_suggested           date,
                                suggested_by             integer,
                                recommendation_date      date,
                                flag_24hours             integer,
                                display_processed        character varying,
                                display_processed_date   date);"
```

ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  missing "=" after "conn_db_link" in connection info string

Any thoughts on what I am missing?  Did I set up the DB Link wrong?  It works manually.....

Comment: Do you have  a config? Please show you conn_db_link

Comment: Perhaps this is my ignorance.  I just followed the steps on this page:  https://medium.com/@techrandomthoughts/setting-up-db-link-in-postgresql-d196468b43f8       And was able to run the statement manually from within psql.   But in the end, I'll need to done in the shell script.

Comment: It is probably a minor type in either your `zrec` or `conn_db_link`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `SELECT dblink_connect('conn_db_link',...)`, you have to repeat it in each session.  The setting does not survive.  However, if you create a foreign server (like 'server_vegeta_remote' in the tutorial) then that does survive between sessions.  You can use the name of the foreign server directly calls in dblink.

I don't see the point of `SELECT dblink_connect('conn_db_link','server_vegeta_remote')` in the tutorial.  Why not just use 'server_vegeta_remote' directly, rather than creating temporary named connection based on it?